# "One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data" or "Failed Stopping"

Tags: r, dataframe, classification

In R, I am trying to bag a data frame like following:

```r
library(datasets)
require(e1071)

fit <- function(x,y,method="rpart", control = rpart.control(maxdepth=1,maxsurrogate = 0)){
  train(x,y,method,control=control)
}

getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

bagged <- bag(x = iris[, names(iris) != "Species"],
              y = iris$Species,
              B=4,
              bagControl = bagControl(
                fit = fit,
                predict = predict,
                aggregate = getmode)
              )
```

and I receive the error message:

```r
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :3     NA's   :3    
Error in fitter(btSamples[[iter]], x = x, y = y, ctrl = bagControl, v = vars,  : 
  task 1 failed - "Stopping"
```

---

Using the function from ldaBag instead, works

```
library(datasets)
require(e1071)

bagged <- bag(x = iris[, names(iris) != "Species"],
              y = iris$Species,
              B=4,
              bagControl = bagControl(
                fit = ldaBag$fit,
                predict = ldaBag$pred,
                aggregate = ldaBag$aggregate)
)
```

---

So what is the issue with my custom fit and aggregate functions?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i required the package rpart

`require(rpart)`

which i found out by testing the code in a different environment, which had warnings enabled - although i never conciously disabled them, they were disabled  in the former environtment.

Thus, i couldn't see the full message:

```
Error in fitter(btSamples[[iter]], x = x, y = y, ctrl = bagControl, v = vars,  : 
  task 1 failed - "Stopping"
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In (function (kind = NULL, normal.kind = NULL, sample.kind = NULL)  ... :
  non-uniform 'Rounding' sampler used
2: model fit failed for Resample01: cp=0 Error in rpart.control(maxdepth = 1, maxsurrogate = 0) : 
  could not find function "rpart.control"
```

I reactiveted warnings using `options(warn=0)`